# Send http requests in Ruby and stay logged in?

Tags: ruby, http, cookies, http-headers, session-cookies

I am trying to crawl websites with ruby. The way I am implementing it is that I send request for a page, and get all the links(href tags) in the page, and then generate another GET request. The problem is that I want to stay logged in during the whole process. I wrote some code as followed.

```
def start_crawling
    uri = URI(@host + "/login")
    @visited.push @host + "/login"
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    req.set_form_data({
      'email' => 'test', 
      'password' => 'test'
    })
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
      res = http.request req
      puts uri
      puts res.code
      content = res.body
      puts content
      puts res.response
      cookie = res.response['Set-Cookie'] # this gives nothing
      puts cookie
      puts res["Set-Cookie"] # prints nothing here
      hrefs = get_href_tag_array_from_html(content)
      send_get_requests(hrefs, cookie)
    end
  end

  def send_get_requests(hrefs, cookie)
    while not hrefs.empty? 
      href = hrefs.pop
      href = @host + href if not href.start_with?"http"
      next if @visited.include?(href)
      puts "href: " + href
      uri = URI(href)

      Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
        req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
        res = http.request req
        puts "------------------href: #{href}---------------------------"
        puts res.code
        puts res.message
        puts res.class.name
        puts "Cookie: "
        puts res['Set-Cookie'] # this works and prints cookies
        puts res.body 
        puts "------------------end of: #{href}---------------------------"
        new_hrefs = get_href_tag_array_from_html(res.body)
        hrefs += new_hrefs
      end
      @visited.push href 
    end
  end
```

I want to start crawling from the login page. Ideally I want to stay logged in during the whole crawling procedure. I don't know much about session/cookie stuff, but I guess if I can get the cookie from the previous response and send it with the next request, I should be able to stay logged in. However, I cannot get any cookie from the login response. The response body is a 302 redirection, as I would expect. I checked it on the browser and the 302 response header does contain a cookie field, and this cookie is used for the next get request to redirect to the home page, but I cannot get the cookie field.

When I send GET request and get the response, I can get the cookie field out of it, but when I send POST request for the login page, I cannot get any cookie. Is there any fundamental difference between GET and POST requests in such cases?

Any idea how can I get this cookie field? Or do I have some basic misunderstanding in solving this crawling problem? Thanks.

Comment: It is really hard to say without offering the web page in question - it could be their fault. Have you tried implementing this with __mechanize__ gem?

Comment: @instinctious Thanks for pointing out this tool. I will try that.